# Azure AD B2C with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I believe Azure AD B2C is great and will lift a lot of weight for many devs. I have a few questions as I stubbornly try to get it in production on my personal apps as soon as possible.

1. Is it ok to use azure ad b2c with angular js as long as we are ok with the id_token expiring every hour and have to make users go back to AAD everytime?
2. If not, is it ok to just use the [graph api](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/) with angular js? (might be a redundant question)
3. If our need is to just return claims and an id_token, Can we use azure ad b2c in production?

   Any help/source code greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1 -2 When the token expires it can be auto renewed without the user having to re-enter their credentials on Azure.

I don't see any reason why you shouldn't use Azure B2c in production. It is in general availability and production ready.

As Azure AD B2C is an implementation of Open ID you may benefit from getting an overview of Open ID. There are may resources on the internet. Here is a quick overview video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdKmZ7mPNns